# Energy difference in the Hamiltonian $H_{b}=\hbar\omega(a^{\dagger}a+\frac{1}{2})+\hbar\omega (b-1/2)(a^{\dagger}a^{\dagger} +aa)$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, harmonic-oscillator

Given that a Hamiltonian is on the form
$$H_{b}=\hbar\omega(a^{\dagger}a+\frac{1}{2})+\hbar\omega (b-\frac{1}{2})(a^{\dagger}a^{\dagger}  +aa)$$
where $b$ is a dimensionless real number in the interval $b\in[0,1)$. 
How can I find the energy difference $∆E=E_1−E_0$ between the first excited energy $E_1$ and the ground state $E_0$ of $H_b$ as a function of $b$. Also, what does this system describe when $b=0$?

Comment: What kind of work have you done in solving this on your own?

Comment: Setting up the rquation $ H_{b} |\psi \rangle =H_{b}\sum ^{\infty }_{n=0} \alpha _{n} |n\rangle =\lambda \sum ^{\infty }_{n=0} \alpha _{n} |n\rangle$. Also $ \sum ^{\infty }_{n=0} \alpha _{n}( H_{b} -\lambda ) |n\rangle =0$. I am trying to find an expression for lambda that does not include the alphas

Comment: Where $|\psi\rangle = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \alpha_n |n\rangle$ and $ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} |\alpha_n|^2$ And $|n\rangle$ are the energy eigenstates